# How to create CSS internal style sheet in CakePHP

Tags: css, cakephp, internal

I have been using CakePHP for a while and recently needed to send emails from an app.  Unfortunately I can not figure out a way to tell CakePHP to include the css directly in the document as an internal style sheet instead of a link.  I know people think that is a bad idea, but my app is only sending emails to our company so I'm not worried too much about someone's email client messing it up.  If I just include the link it doesn't work since the reference is wrong, although if I could make the link an absolute link (http://myserver/css/myfile.css instead of /css/myfile.css) that would be a 2nd best alternative since they would have access to my server.

If there isn't a way to do it in Cake, is there a quick way to just use PHP to read the contents of the file and dump it in the view?  I guess I could do that from the controller, sounds like a bad hack though.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `readfile()` to print the file content directly in your view.

Or you could `$this->Html->url('css/yourcss.css', true)` to get the full path to the file and pass it too the css method.

Comment: I think this is the way to go and have already implemented working code. In my controller I just added this:

`$cssFiles = array('reset','cake.generic','simrav');`
`$cssFiles = array('cake.generic');`
`$this->set(compact('cssFiles'));`

And in my email template I added this to the body (not the head):

`<body>`
`<?php`
`foreach ($cssFiles as $css) {`
` $file = new File('CSS'.DS.$css.'.css');`
` $data = $file->read(false,'r',false);`
` echo "<style type=\"text/css\">".$data."</style>";`
`}`
`?>`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to use php variable as style class and use it directly as css class. For example.

```
$class1 = "border : 1px solid #eeeeee; font-family : font1, font2, font3; color : #785634;"
```

And use it in your email template as

```
<div id='my-div' style=<?php echo $class1; ?>>Your div content </div>
```

Even I do not know any way to include style sheet in the email, and if you create some classes those will not work in email templates.

So this is how I'm using css in my projects.

Comment: Interesting, kind of half way from a css stylesheet to inline.

Answer (score 1):

you can put the css in email layout like normal html (use html email layout)

> ```
> <style type="text/css"></style>
> ```

Comment: Yes but I was trying to reuse the same style as my app without creating a second copy of everything.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the [code of the htmlHelper](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/html-helper/#line-336) shows that it can't be done.

However, you can change or overload the helper; to do so in the simplest way just add a new option between line 371 to 378.

Answer (score 0):

I used PHP's include function enclosed in a script tag and it worked perfectly!  In the default email view:

```
<script>
    include('css/your_css_doc.css');`
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write css inline:

```
 <h2 style="color:#818381">Here are the latest stories everyone's talking about...</h2>
```